# If self-signed SSL certificate is added to Trusted Root Certification Authorities, is there no need to add the cert to WebClient ClientCertificates?

Tags: .net, ssl, webclient, self-signed

Does .NET `WebClient` automatically fetch a self-signed SSL certificate from the Local Computer Trusted Root Certification Authorities without the programmer having to tell it to do so?

We created a self-signed SSL certificate for an intranet web server (internal departmental apps, not public-facing) and then we imported the SSL certificate into Local Computer Trusted Root Certification Authorities on a test PC on the LAN. Edge and Chrome show the lock icon when we type  `https://ourinternalserver/app1` into the browser address bar.

In our proof-of-concept .NET application running on the same test PC, the `System.Net.WebClient` instance is able to set the `BaseAddress` to `https://ourserver/app1` and invoke the `DownloadString` method with success.  Is that all there is to it? It's transparent? There's no need to override the `GetWebRequest` method and explicitly add a Client Certificate?

Comment: For a real world certificate chain, `WebClient` must be served with a client certificate, while its dependencies (intermediate and CA certificates) are installed to the corresponding Windows certificate stores. In your case, a self-signed certificate plays both roles, so you have to do both for it.

Comment: @Lex Li:  When you say that we "have to do both for it" do you mean that both the  client certificate and the dependencies (intermediate and CA certificates) must be explicitly added to the `request.ClientCertificates` collection by our program?   If we do not add them, is the SSL encryption not there?